# how to trim an image in Gimp

Tags: gimp, crop, white-space

I wanna trim all white spaces surrounding an image's content using Gimp. Is there some straightforward method, or any trick?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how this question may be wrong? I got 2 answers of what i exactly wanted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What do you have there that

`Image->Autocrop image` did not work?

Comment: As of Gimp 2.10.8, if I'm not wrong, it appears "Autocrop image" has been renamed to "Crop to Selection".

Comment: "Crop to content" does what I wanted. I don't think "crop to selection" is what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

To trim white borders with **Gimp** we may

1. select the white border with the *Select by Color Tool* [image]
2. Invert the selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

   [image]
3. Crop the image to the selection (*Image > Crop to selection*)

   [image]

For a quicker workflow we can also use the following steps:

1. Select all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Subtract *selection by color* by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouseclick on selecting
3. Crop image to selection

---

Batch processing of large numbers of files can better be done with [**ImageMagick** Trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) to remove all colors having the same color as the image corners:

```
mogrify -trim *.png
```

Note that this will overwrite your files, work on copies.

Comment: Isn't perhaps [autocrop](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-autocrop.html) even faster?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini: yeah it sure is... I was under the impression that the OP didn't have access to this plugin (or may not be satisfied with it for reasons we don't know yet).

Comment: It would be strange not to have access to a plug-in that comes with GIMP by default.